# Informatica Powercenter Add Select LISTAGG query

Tags: oracle, informatica, listagg

I have learning informatica powercenter. I was able to do an INNER JOIN between two VIEWs. I added the INNER JOIN in the User Defined Join but still have to make correct changes in the Sql Query when click on Validate. Do I just need to only add to User Defined Join when I am joining VIEWS?

Here is my problem. I got another VIEWs which is one to many, so this will be my 3rd VIEW to add to the query. I got this running on TOAD. How do I add this to Infromatica? Do I just avoid the Sql Query section and add the entire query into User Defined Query? Do LISTAGG works in Informatica?

If not in the Query for LISTAGG (one-many relationship), is it better or is there a way to do this in the transformation like expression transformation?

Thanks.

This query is a SELECT, LISTAGG, CASE

```
SELECT PERSON_ID, 
       FIRST_NAME,
       MIDDLE_NAME,
       LAST_NAME,
       LISTAGG(val,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Table2.SKILL_SHORT_DESC )  

FROM (SELECT DISTINCT  Table1.PERSON_ID, 
       Table1.FIRST_NAME,
       Table1.MIDDLE_NAME,
       Table1.LAST_NAME,
       (case  
            when Table2.SKILL_SHORT_DESC = '1' then '1:1'
            when Table2.SKILL_SHORT_DESC = '2' then '2:2'
            when Table2.SKILL_SHORT_DESC = '3' then '3:3'
            when Table2.SKILL_SHORT_DESC = '4' then '4:4'
            when Table2.SKILL_SHORT_DESC = '5' then '5:5'
            when Table2.SKILL_SHORT_DESC = '6' then '6:6'
            when Table2.SKILL_SHORT_DESC = '7' then '7:7'
            when Table2.SKILL_SHORT_DESC = '8' then '8:8'
            when Table2.SKILL_SHORT_DESC = '9' then '9:9'


            else ''

        end) as val  

FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2

ON Table2.PERSON_ID = Table1.PERSON_ID
)
GROUP BY PERSON_ID,FIRST_NAME,MIDDLE_NAME, LAST_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, LISTAGG should work. Assuming you are using oracle, it should work 10.x and higher version. Frankly, Informatica doesn't care what you write as SQL but its the database where SQL is being issued matters. You can write 'I am batman' and infa will return, 'Invalid syntax'.

Koushik

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps,

1. Get any dummy source from the table
2. In source qualifier, remove all the ports and create the ports you required
3. In properties --> Sql query, add the query you have created. No need to provide any user defined joins

Below are the screen shots for better understanding.

[image]

[image]